# Cannot build an Action

Tags: scala, playframework

I am running a Play 2.6 application and I am experimenting with building actions. When I try to compile this code from the online documentation it fails:

```
import play.api.mvc._

case class Logging[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {

  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    Logger.info("Calling action")
    action(request)
  }

  override def parser = action.parser
  override def executionContext = action.executionContext
}
```

There are no fields called parser and executionContent on the action value. Instead the IDE is telling me that I need to implement the following method:

```
override def call(ctx: Http.Context) : CompletionStage[mvc.Result] = ???
```

How do I implement this? The code works with Play 2.5 but not Play 2.6. Is this because it changed to AkkaHttp underneath from Netty?

Comment: Do you have a link to that documentation? Is it really for 2.6? Play changes how you have to code against it between versions.

Comment: This compiles fine for me on Play 2.6.20

Comment: @Thilo https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: @Lasf I am using 2.6.16

Comment: @Lasf I tried with 2.6.20 and still the same. Not sure how you are getting it to compile

Comment: @Lasf I created a fresh Play project and used 2.6.20 and it doesn't compile. Are you sure you are using the right plugin?

Comment: Is this a problem in the IDE only? Can `sbt` compile it?

Comment: @Thilo I tried to compile the fresh project with sbt and it is the same problem, it is not Intellij.

Comment: I think Typesafe have changed the API but the document is old and out of sync. The code works with 2.5.12.

Comment: `CompletionStage` is a Java API. Can you double-check the `import` statement to make sure you are using the Scala API?

Comment: Yes I noticed that. It is weird. I am importing `play.mvc.Action` but when I click on that type in Intellij it is taking me to a Java abstract class.

Comment: `play.mvc.Action` is the Java version. You want `play.api.mvc.Action`.

Comment: @Thilo, yes you are right!! Thanks mate. Fucking Intellij imported the Java version,